# Can't extract information of a file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to do a script in Python that reads a file (`A.out`) and when it detects a keyword starts copying the file `A.out` into `B.out`.

The file `A.out` is something like:

```
 CYCLE:   194 TIME:   0.025 TIME LEFT:  2.00D  GRAD.:     1.872 HEAT: -420.1845
 CYCLE:   195 TIME:   0.025 TIME LEFT:  2.00D  GRAD.:     2.232 HEAT: -420.1653
 CYCLE:   196 TIME:   0.025 TIME LEFT:  2.00D  GRAD.:     1.981 HEAT: -420.1703


          EXCESS NUMBER OF OPTIMIZATION CYCLES


          CURRENT VALUE OF GRADIENT NORM =    1.890706

          CURRENT VALUE OF GEOMETRY




  C    -2.05768505 +1   4.28867630 +1   0.07135650 +1
  O    -0.75590874 +1   4.69719052 +1  -0.38910531 +1
  H    -0.78776710 +1   4.91862889 +1  -1.39007889 +1
  C    -2.73026659 +1   3.32072929 +1  -0.89832955 +1

# it ends here
```

The script i made is supposed to find the "CURRENT VALUE OF GEOMETRY" and 4 lines later start copying info from "A" to "B". But it is not working.
The code is:

```
import os

from os.path import exists, splitext


def out_to_mop_let (fileA, fileB, keywords=""):
    fileA="A.out"
    fileB="B.out"
    filein=open(fileA, "r")
    fileout=open(fileB, "w")
    lines = filein.readlines()
    filein.close()

    lstart = None
    lfinish = None

    for lindex in range(0,len(lines)):
        if lindex-4>lstart and lines[lindex]=='\n' and lfinish==None and lstart!=None:
            lfinish=lindex+1
        if " CURRENT VALUE OF GEOMETRY" in lines[lindex]:
            lstart=lindex 
    print lstart
    print lfinish
    fileout.write(keywords + "\n\n\n")
    for lindex in range(lstart+4,lfinish):
        fileout.write(lines[lindex])

    fileout.close()
    filein.close()
```

But when I execute it, the terminal returns:

```
    for lindex in range(lstart+4,lfinish):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I don't know how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: As a punctual response to "Why am I getting this NoneType error" question: it's because you are trying to use a None object instead of an integer in your range function. Try printing the values of lstart and lfinish to figure out why. My best guess, without running your code, is that lstart is still None when you try to add 4 to it.

Comment: You set lstart and lfinish to "None" and then do operations on them. What did you expect?

I am surprised the error didn't already get thrown on the first for-loop, as the `>` operator also doesn't take None as an argument.
The fact that you didn't get an error there implies that the first loop wasn't entered which means lines is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit shorter and more pythonic:

```
with open('A.out') as fin, open('B.out', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.strip() == 'CURRENT VALUE OF GEOMETRY':
            break
    for line in fin:
        if line.strip():
            fout.write(line)
```

### Explanation

It is recommend to  use the `with` statement when for opening files.
This create a so called context. As soon as you dedent, i.e. leave the context, the file will be automatically close.

Here, I open both files, the source and the destination, with one `with` statement.
Both will closed upon leaving the context.

A file object is an iterator and allows direct iteration with a `for` loop.
Use `line.strip()` to get rid of any leading and trailing white spaces.
As soon as you see `CURRENT VALUE OF GEOMETRY` on a cleaned line, change into a different mode and start copying all non-empty lines from `A.out` to `B.out`.

Comment: Great, thanks, i will try it. Is here contained the restriction of the 4 lines?

Comment: I don't look for the number of empty lines. I just copy all non-empty lines.

Comment: You are missing a ':'.

Comment: wow..unbelievable for me. It works. To learn a bit more of programming, what should i read or see? I have made only a very basic course in EDX

Comment: This should give enough materiel for a while: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0):

you're setting lfinish to None and then try doing arithmetic on it, which doesn't work.

One possible solution would be:

```
def from_A_to_B (Aout, Bout):
    filein=open(Aout, "r")
    fileout=open(Bout, "w")
    lines = filein.readlines()

    found = False
    for line in lines:
        if not found and "CURRENT VALUE OF GEOMETRY" in line:
            found = True
        elif found:
            fileout.write(line)

    fileout.close()
    filein.close()
```